# In SQL Server how to reduce query execution time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The tables I used in the query contain lot's of records. It's taken more than 1 min to fetch the records from the database. I am using the group by and outer apply both. Can anyone help me how can I optimize the query so it will take less execution time.

Stored procedure query:

```
DECLARE @BankAccount NVARCHAR(200) = NULL,  
        @Bank NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,  
        @AccountType NVARCHAR(200) = NULL,  
        @Status NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,  
        @Agent NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,  
        @Month NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,  
        @FromDate DATETIME ='2000-01-01',  
        @ToDate DATETIME = '2022-01-01',
    
        @pagenumber INT = 1,  
        @pagesize INT = 20
    
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsMonthNull INT = 0, 
            @recordExistInPrevMonth INT = 0, 
            @isPreviousMonth DATETIME = NULL;
    
    SELECT 
        rslt.TotalRows,
        rslt.BRSAccountID,
        rslt._AccountNumber,
        rslt.OpeningBalance, 
        rslt.Credits, 
        rslt.Debits, 
        rslt.ClosingBalance, 
        rslt.DateRangeFrom, 
        rslt.DateRangeTo,
        rslt._Bank,
        rslt._Agent 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             COUNT(bt.AccountNumber) OVER() TotalRows, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER  BY bt.AccountNumber ASC) AS RowNumber,
             bt.BRSAccountID,
             bt.AccountNumber AS _AccountNumber,
             CAST((CASE
                       WHEN @IsMonthNull = 1 
                           THEN ISNULL(BankTransactionOpngBalance.OpeningBalance, 0) 
                           ELSE ISNULL(Opng.OpeningBalance, 0)
                   END) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) OpeningBalance,  
             CAST(cdt.Credits AS varchar(max)) AS Credits,
             CAST(dbt.Debits AS varchar(max)) AS Debits,  
             CAST((CASE 
                       WHEN ISNULL(Clsg.ClosingBalance, 0) = 0 
                           THEN ClsgNew.ClosingBalance  
                       WHEN @IsMonthNull = 1 
                           THEN ISNULL(ClsgNew.ClosingBalance, 0) 
                       ELSE Clsg.ClosingBalance 
                   END) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) ClosingBalance,   
             CAST(@FromDate AS VARCHAR(MAX)) DateRangeFrom,
             CAST(@ToDate AS VARCHAR(MAX)) DateRangeTo,
             bt.Bank As _Bank,
             CAST(ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 ag.AssignedAgent AS AssignedAgent  
                          FROM RecConfig ag 
                          WHERE ag.BRSAccountID = bt.BRSAccountID), 0) AS varchar(max)) AS _Agent
         FROM 
             BankTransaction as bt
         INNER JOIN 
             BankAccountsReconciliation rec ON bt.BRSAccountID = rec.BRSAccountID  
                                            AND bt.AccountNumber = bt.AccountNumber
         OUTER APPLY 
             (SELECT TOP 1 BankBalance AS OpeningBalance   
              FROM BankPeriodEndBalance bal  
              WHERE bal.BRSAccountId = bt.BRSAccountID 
                AND CAST(bal.PeriodEndDate AS DATE) >= CAST(@FromDate AS DATE) 
                AND CAST(bal.PeriodEndDate AS DATE) <= CAST(@ToDate AS DATE)  
              ORDER BY bal.PeriodEndDate DESC) Opng  
         OUTER APPLY
             (SELECT TOP 1 bnkTrans.Closing_Balance AS OpeningBalance   
              FROM BankTransaction bnkTrans  
              WHERE bnkTrans.BRSAccountId = bt.BRSAccountID 
                AND CAST(bnkTrans.Date AS DATE) < CAST(@FromDate AS DATE)   
              ORDER BY bnkTrans.Date  DESC) BankTransactionOpngBalance 
         OUTER APPLY  
             (SELECT SUM(bnkt.Amount) AS Credits 
              FROM BankTransaction bnkt  
              WHERE bnkt.Debit_Credit = 'CR' 
                AND bnkt.BRSAccountID = bt.BRSAccountID  
                AND CAST(bnkt.Date AS DATE) >= CAST(@FromDate AS DATE) 
                AND CAST(bnkt.Date AS DATE) <= CAST(@ToDate AS DATE)) cdt
         OUTER APPLY 
             (SELECT SUM(bnkt.Amount) AS Debits 
              FROM BankTransaction bnkt  
              WHERE bnkt.Debit_Credit = 'DR' 
                AND bnkt.BRSAccountID = bt.BRSAccountID  
                AND CAST(bnkt.Date AS DATE) >= CAST(@FromDate AS DATE) 
                AND CAST(bnkt.Date AS DATE) <= CAST(@ToDate AS DATE)) dbt
         OUTER APPLY 
             (SELECT TOP 1 BankBalance AS ClosingBalance 
              FROM BankPeriodEndBalance bal  
              WHERE bal.BRSAccountId = bt.BRSAccountID 
                AND CAST(bal.PeriodEndDate AS DATE) <= CAST(@ToDate AS DATE) 
                AND CAST(bal.PeriodEndDate AS DATE) >= CAST(@FromDate AS DATE)  
              ORDER BY bal.PeriodEndDate DESC) Clsg  
         OUTER APPLY 
             (SELECT TOP 1 bal.Closing_Balance AS ClosingBalance 
              FROM BankTransaction bal  
              WHERE bal.BRSAccountId = bt.BRSAccountID 
                AND CAST(bal.Date AS DATE) <= CAST(@ToDate AS DATE) 
                AND CAST(bal.Date AS DATE) >= CAST(@FromDate AS DATE)  
              ORDER BY bal.date DESC) ClsgNew 
         WHERE  
             bt.AccountNumber  = ISNULL(@BankAccount, bt.AccountNumber) 
             AND CAST(bt.Date AS DATE) <= CAST(@ToDate AS DATE) 
             AND CAST(bt.Date AS DATE) >= CAST(@FromDate AS DATE) 
             AND (LEFT(bt.BSB, 2) = ISNULL(@Bank, LEFT(bt.BSB, 2))) 
             AND rec.Status = ISNULL(@Status, rec.Status)
             AND rec.AccountTypeId = ISNULL(@AccountType, rec.AccountTypeId)
         GROUP BY
             bt.AccountNumber, bt.BRSAccountID, 
             BankTransactionOpngBalance.OpeningBalance, 
             Opng.OpeningBalance, cdt.Credits, dbt.Debits,
             clsg.ClosingBalance, ClsgNew.ClosingBalance, bt.Bank) rslt
    WHERE 
        ((@Agent Is NOT NULL AND _Agent = @Agent) OR @Agent IS NULL) 
        AND RowNumber BETWEEN ((@pagenumber-1) * @PageSize) + 1 AND((@pagenumber-1) * @PageSize) + 1 + @PageSize -1 
     OPTION (RECOMPILE)
END
```

The above query is working fine but sometimes takes more than 2 minutes.

Comment: Is this a Stored Procedure? If so, have you looked into Parameter Sniffing?

Comment: You need to inspect and provide us with the execution plan (using Paste The Plan). And you need to provide your indexes on the relevant tables. A query tells SQL Server the results you want, it doesn't specify how SQL Server should obtain those results. Therefore we can't offer (much) performance advice just by seeing the query.

Comment: There's a lot of improvements you can make but as mentioned the execution plan is cruicial to determine which element(s) are consuming the most resources. Why, for example, are you casting string values as varchar(max)? Do you *really* expect a date to require >8kb of space...? SQL Server uses things like string length to determine expected memory allocation requirements, so don't just throw (max) at everything.

Comment: All those subqueries are not helping you here. You have multiple queries hitting the same table. There are also some strange conversions to varchar(max). My guess is there is a lot of room for improvement from a performance standpoint. But without table definitions, indexes, approximate row counts, execution plan and such nobody can do much to offer any specific help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

Using index significantly reduces the time of execution. Index implements the b tree algorithm and the downside to reduced time of execution is the extra space needed and a few seconds to build the index. Insertion, deletion might also take longer but querying is much faster.

Comment: Thats a general tip, suited to a comment, but its not a specific answer.